# Using Reduce to rearrange an Object of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I am trying to get the below output from the array using reduce, however, I can't wrap my head about some parts on how reduce behave , appreciate some explanation so I can fully grasp it.

final goal is after reducing the result into a single array, removing duplicate objects based on the vch_number

Reduce function

```
const result = car.reduce((acc,vch)=>{

const temp = {...acc,[vch.name]:vch.Vehciles}
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(temp)){
  const fillterd = value.map(item => {
    item.status = key
    return item
  })
}

return temp
}
  ,{})
console.log(result)
```

// final desired output vs current output

```
current = { available: 
   [ { make: 'bwm',
       model: 'i8',
       year: 2000,
       vch_number: 51511,
       status: 'available' },
     { make: 'bwm',
       model: 'i8',
       year: 2020,
       vch_number: 51541,
       status: 'available' } ],
  parked: 
   [ { make: 'bwm',
       model: 'i8',
       year: 2000,
       vch_number: 51510,
       status: 'parked' } ],
  service: 
   [ { make: 'bwm',
       model: 'i8',
       year: 2000,
       vch_number: 51510,
       status: 'service' } ] }




desired = [ 
        { make: 'bwm',
           model: 'i8',
           year: 2000,
           vch_number: 51511,
           status: 'available' },
         { make: 'bwm',
           model: 'i8',
           year: 2020,
           vch_number: 51541,
           status: 'available' },
    
       { make: 'bwm',
           model: 'i8',
           year: 2000,
           vch_number: 51510,
           status: 'parked' } ,
    
       { make: 'bwm',
           model: 'i8',
           year: 2000,
           vch_number: 51510,
           status: 'service' }
       ]
```

// Original API array

```
    const car = [
    {
        "name": "available",
        "Vehciles": [
            {
                "make": "bwm",
                "model": "i8",
                "year": 2000,
                "vch_number": 51511,
            },
                        {
                "make": "bwm",
                "model": "i8",
                "year": 2020,
                "vch_number": 51541,

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "parked",
        "Vehciles": [
            {
                "make": "bwm",
                "model": "i8",
                "year": 2000,
                "vch_number": 51510,

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "service",
        "Vehciles": [
            {
                "make": "bwm",
                "model": "i8",
                "year": 2000,
                "vch_number": 51510,

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: what is with `51510`? why it it twice in the result set?

Comment: There is time-stamps on each object that I didn't add to this array!

Comment: which property is relevant to decide, if duplicate?

Comment: on the API there is this nested object on each props that I removed to reduce the complexity & the created at was my relevant prop with the vch number `"VehcileStatus": {
                    "statusId": 2,
                    "createdAt": "2021-03-16T01:39:48.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-03-16T01:39:48.000Z"
                }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is your using a `{}` as the second argument (the so called `accumulator`) in the `.reduce()` function. You'll want to pass an empty array `[]`.
Second off all you have the `Vehciles` array inside those objects so you have to perform one more transformation inside.

more about reducers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

I think the key is to wrap your head around the `initialValue` and the `accumulator` and how it relates to the `currentValue` when it comes to `Array.reduce()`

I've whipped up this code:

```js
const car = [
    {
        "name": "available",
        "Vehciles": [
            {
                "make": "bwm",
                "model": "i8",
                "year": 2000,
                "vch_number": 51511,
            },
                        {
                "make": "bwm",
                "model": "i8",
                "year": 2020,
                "vch_number": 51541,

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "parked",
        "Vehciles": [
            {
                "make": "bwm",
                "model": "i8",
                "year": 2000,
                "vch_number": 51510,

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "service",
        "Vehciles": [
            {
                "make": "bwm",
                "model": "i8",
                "year": 2000,
                "vch_number": 51510,

            }
        ]
    }
];

const result = car.reduce((acc,vch)=>{
  const cars = vch.Vehciles.map(vehicle => {
    const temp = {
        status: vch.name,
        ...vehicle
      };  
    return temp;
  }).reduce((carAcc, car) => {
    carAcc.push(car);
    return carAcc;
  }, acc);
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I am sorry Filip, where is the carAcc array in the second reduce is coming from?

Comment: So, because your goal is to flatten the whole data into a single array. We first pass an empty `[]` as the `accumulator` in the first `reduce` we get it as an argument `acc`. Then we pass the `acc` to the second internal `reduce` that is already reducing an array modified by the `map` (which 'injects' the `status: vch.name`). We get the `acc` in the internal `reduce` callback as `carAcc`. So TLDR; `result`, `acc` and `carAcc` are the same Array `[]` that we passed as the second argument to the topmost `reduce`. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could map the objects and check with a `Set`.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "available", Vehciles: [{ make: "bwm", model: "i8", year: 2000, vch_number: 51511 }, { make: "bwm", model: "i8", year: 2020, vch_number: 51541 }] }, { name: "parked", Vehciles: [{ make: "bwm", model: "i8", year: 2000, vch_number: 51510 }] }, { name: "service", Vehciles: [{ make: "bwm", model: "i8", year: 2000, vch_number: 51510 }] }],
    result = data.flatMap(
        (seen => ({ name: status, Vehciles }) => Vehciles.flatMap(o => seen.has(o.vch_number) 
            ? []
            : (seen.add(o.vch_number), { ...o, status })
        ))
        (new Set)
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! is it possible to use async with reduce to incorporate new Set results ?

Comment: i have no idea. please try yourself.

Comment: Thank you Nina for your help!